# MongoDB - get all elements matching a condition in "deep" array

Tags: mongodb

My `users` collection contains:

```
{
    _id: "1",
    posts: [
        {
            _id: "12",
            comments: [
                {
                    _id: "123",
                    userId: "5",
                    ...
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
},
...
```

I want to get all the comments the belongs to specific user id (userId prop).

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "posts.comments.user": "userId1" // note that you need to use objectId here if the user property in the comments array is an objectId
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$posts"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "posts.comments": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$posts.comments",
          as: "comment",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$comment.user",
              "userId1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      posts: {
        $push: "$posts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

test it here  [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wl5qDzjDzfY)

---

### > Update

the above query will get an array of documents, each document has posts array, and each post element has comments array

if you need just the comments array belong to some user, then we can use something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "posts.comments.user": "userId1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$posts"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "posts.comments": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$posts.comments",
          as: "comment",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$comment.user",
              "userId1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$posts.comments"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      comments: {
        $push: "$posts.comments"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

and test it here [Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m9pb3K3sgDq)

Comment: Is it efficient to first unwind the posts property of all users? Isn't it will be better to first match users that contains offers with the given userId?

Comment: yes of course, I've updated my answer, could you check it now?

Comment: note that you need to use ObjectId in $match if the user property is of type ObjectId

Comment: It works well! But in the end i need an array of comments, should i do it in Javascript and not in the aggregation?

Comment: you need an array of comments directly, without posts then comments inside it?

Comment: Yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: could you try this https://mongoplayground.net/p/m9pb3K3sgDq, If that's okay, just let me know to update the answer